# Are integers ever used in calculations involving hypercomplex numbers?

Tags: integers, hypercomplex-numbers

Integers are of course used in calculations involving complex numbers.  But are integers ever used in calculations involving quaternions, octonions, etc.?  In essence, are integers ever used in complex-valued systems that don't commute?

For extra credit, are there applications that we can list where integers are used with these hypercomplex numbers?

** EDIT **

I'm really just looking for applications that involve quaternions, octonions, etc. and that use integer values instead of real values for each element.  I really can't seem to find any, so I'm hoping that someone can list some.

Comment: How are integers used in complex numbers ? And if so, why not in quaternions the same way ?

Comment: What does it mean "integers are used" ?

Comment: Whatever you mean, you may be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_quaternion and their use in the proof of the four square theorem.

Comment: @DietrichBurde:  I was really just trying to ask for applications of hypercomplexes combined with integers.  I edited the question, in the hopes that it's more clear.

Comment: @CaptainLama:  I meant "applications".  Anyways, thanks for the link - it mentions "Lipschitz quaternions" among other useful information, and these alone are a good starting point, not to mention the other good stuff.